# Pass variable to nawk in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, nawk

I'm trying to pass a variable to `nawk` in a bash script, but it's not actually printing the `$commentValue` variable's contents. Everything works great, except the last part of the printf statement.  Thanks!

```
echo -n "Service Name: "

read serviceName

echo -n "Comment: "

read commentValue

for check in $(grep "CURRENT SERVICE STATE"  $nagiosLog |grep -w "$serviceName" | nawk -F": " '{print $2}' |sort -u ) ; do
    echo $check | nawk -F";" -v now=$now '{ printf( "[%u]=ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM;"$1";"$2";2;1;0;admin;$commentValue"\n", now)}' >> $nagiosCommand

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$commentValue` is inside an invocation to `nawk`, so it is considered as a variable in `nawk`, not a variable in `bash`. Since you do not have such a variable in `nawk`, you won't get anything there. You should first pass the variable "inside" `nawk` using the `-v` switch just like you did for the `now` variable; i.e.:

```
... | nawk -F";" -v now=$now -v "commentValue=$commentValue"
```

Note the quotes - they are required in case `$commentValue` contains whitespace.

Comment: Hmm, I've modified the command, but it still just prints the word "commentValue" instead of the contents.  echo $check | nawk -F";" -v now=$now -v "commentValue=$commentValue" '{ printf( "[%u]=ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM;"$1";"$2";2;1;0;admin;commentValue\n", now)}' >> $nagiosCommand

Comment: It should be: ``echo $check | nawk -F";" -v now=$now -v "commentValue=$commentValue" '{ printf( "[%u]=ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM;"$1";"$2";2;1;0;admin;%s\n", now, commentValue)}' >> $nagiosCommand``. Please read the documentation of ``printf`` in the ``awk`` manual.

Comment: Ahhhh, duh. I had done that previously, but lef the trailing " at the very end. Thank you!